# Negative exponentiation for Encryption / Decryption using Fast Exponentiation

Tags: java, encryption

All,

I have coded Fast exponentiation algorithm to check if the encrypted value is equal to the original value for a given exponent (e) and modulo base (n). When I have a negative exponent, the values are not the same. Here is what I do:

1 > Any value `base`
2 > Private key `prKey`
3 > Public key `puKey`
4 > Modulo base `modN`

Decrypt using `base` ^ `prKey` mod `modN` to get `decryptVal`
then encrypt `decryptVal` ^ `puKey` mod `modN` to get `encryptVal`

Now `encryptVal` should be equal to `base`. In my code, this condition is satisfied for positive values of private key `prKey` **only**. For negative values of `prKey`, the condition is never satisfied.

Example (from my code run for various random values):

1 > `base`:  4092
2 > `modN` = 6499
3 > `puKey` =  5
4 > `prKey` = -1267

would give `decryptVal` = 4092 and `encryptVal` = 5537 != `base`

whereas when,

1 > `base`:  249
2 > `modN` = 6059
3 > `puKey` =  5
4 > `prKey` = 1181

gives me `decryptVal` = 4067 and `encryptVal` = 249 = `base`

Is this condition the expected behavior or there is a flaw in my code based on above execution results?
[Note]: `prKey` and `puKey` are computed using Extended Euclidean algorithm

Comment: How do you calculate `value^exp` with a negative exponent?

Comment: "...Is there a flaw in my code..."
I see no code.

Comment: @Progman: Using Fast Exponentiation algorithm!!  @GregS: I am verifying if negative exponents always cause for different values when encrypting and decrypting. I have confirmed that my values are correct by using BigInteger.modPow() as well. It's just that I am not sure if negative exponents always result in different values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read through your post twice and cannot quite understand what the problem is. You ask if there is a flaw in your code but you haven't shown any code. Anyway, the usual definition of exponentiation `a`<sup>`x`</sup> `mod n` for negative x requires that gcd(a,n) = 1. If `gcd(a,n) = 1` then `a`<sup>x</sup>`mod n` == (`a`<sup>`-1`</sup>)<sup>`-x`</sup> `mod n`. So if `x` is negative first compute the inverse of `a` and then raise that to the `-x` power, all `mod n`.